# OpenGL/GLSL/LWJGL return value from shader

Tags: shaders, glsl, lwjgl

I'm trying to do some bone animation. I don't want the whole skeleton to be loaded to the GLSL shader every time, even tough it's not needed, because one vertex is parented to one bone, not more. My question is simple: (How) can i return some value from the vertex shader back to my code? I'm using LWJGL/Java

Comment: Believe it or not, you actually *cant*. What you *can* do is write pixels out to a buffer, and then read the buffer later.

Comment: There is also GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER atomic increments, and the transform feedback buffer in Daniel Carlsson's answer below. Watching answers carefully, this is an interesting question to me...

Comment: Ok, then I just load the whole Skeleton into the shader, isn't a huge thing, but could impact performance :/

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [Transform Feedback Buffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback) to output from your vertex shader, your question is not very specific though so I can't be sure if this is truly what you want to do.

Comment: Can TFB be used by the CPU to conditionalize some of the later rendering? (The OP seems to imply that this what they want; they may be not approaching their particular problem right though, not sure.)

Comment: Yes you can, but as always when reading buffers from the CPU you have to keep in mind that the buffer might not be filled yet just because your rendering the next frame in the CPU. You need to use `glFenceSync​` to make sure you have valid output in the buffer.